# MSG 1776 SQL "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am creating tables and I am getting a Foreign Key Constraint Error and says that the table doesn't have a primary key or candidate key in the referenced table. But I do.

```
CREATE TABLE TCourses 
(
 intCourseID                        INTEGER                         NOT NULL
,strCourse                          VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL
,strDescription                     VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL
,intRoomID                          INTEGER                         NOT NULL
,intInstructorID                    INTEGER                         NOT NULL
,intBookID                          INTEGER                         NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT  TCourses_PK                     PRIMARY KEY ( intCourseID )
);

CREATE TABLE TBooks
(
 intBookID                          INTEGER                         NOT NULL
,intAuthorID                        INTEGER                         NOT NULL
,intAuthorIndex                     INTEGER                         NOT NULL
,strBookTitle                       VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL
,strBookISBN                        VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT TBooks_PK                        PRIMARY KEY ( intBookID, intAuthorID, intAuthorIndex )
);


--3


ALTER TABLE TCourses    ​ADD CONSTRAINT TCourses_TBooks_FK


FOREIGN KEY (intBookID) REFERENCES TBooks (intBookID)
```

Comment: Paste the actual code. Your CREATE TABLE statements can't possibly run as they are now.

Comment: tbooks has a composite primary key (three things).  your foreign key reference only points to one. probably has to do with all of that...

Comment: make `tbook_id` your primary key in tbooks.  this will fix your foreign key reference.  if you need the other fields in tbooks to be unique, add a unique constraint.

Comment: I have intAuthorID as a Primary key key in the TAuthors Table just fine and that is a Foreign key. Just intBookID does not want to be the foreign key in the TCourses Table.

Comment: I have even changed  it to intCourseID, intBookID, intAuthorID removed the intAuthorIndex and it will allow intCourseID and intAuthorID to be a foreign key but not intBookID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I figured it out. If I left it the way it was strBookISBN was going to be a hidden repeating group. So I needed TCourses, TBooks, TCourseBooks for it to work. Were TCourseBooks is my relationship table.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: When you are back, please consider accepting your answer formally. That way your question will look as resolved in a list of questions and people won't waste their time opening it.